# React Material UI Tabs with Router Link Active tab appears on second click

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I am using material-ui react tabs along with the Router link and everything works fine except from the active tab. The active tab is selected after the user has clicked twice the tab although the content is shown at the first click.

It seems as it reinitializes the value to the initial one and in the second click it updates.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = useState(4);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] =  useState(null);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  }


    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Paper>
            <Tabs
              value={value}
              variant="standard"
              indicatorColor="primary"
              textColor="primary"
              selectionFollowsFocus="true"
              onChange={handleChange}
              centered>

              <Tab component={Link}
                   to="/balances"
                   icon={<AccountBalance />}
                   label="..."/>
              <Tab component={Link}
                   to="/finalisations"
                   icon={<LabelImportant />}
                   label="..." />
              <Tab component={Link}
                   to="/publications"
                   icon={<Public />}
                   label="..." />
              <Tab component={Link}
                   to="/models"
                   icon={<FormatAlignCenter />}
                   label="ΥΠΟΔΕΙΓΜΑΤΑ" />
              <Tab  component={Link}
                    to="/accounts"
                    icon={<AccountBox />}
                    label="..." />
              <Tab  component={Link}
                    to="/users"
                    icon={<People />}
                    label="..."/>

            </Tabs>
```

Comment: Can you put that in a codesandbox?

Comment: By trying to put the code in a sandbox I got a warning that Link component from react-router-dom can't be outside of the router. So I added the tabs code within the rooter component and that solved the problem. Thank you for prompting me to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { AppBar, Tab, Tabs } from '@material-ui/core'
import {
 Apps,
 Event,
 Equalizer,
 ShoppingBasket,
} from '@material-ui/icons'


function a11yProps(index) {
 return {
  id: `scrollable-force-tab-${index}`,
  'aria-controls': `scrollable-force-tabpanel-${index}`,
 }
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
 root: {
  flexGrow: 1,
  width: '100%',
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
 },
 tabs: {
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: 'center',
 },
}))

const NavBarItem = {
 '/schedule': 0,
 '/reports': 1,
 '/utils': 2,
 '/sale-management': 3,
}

const NavBar = ({ location, history }) => {
 const classes = useStyles()
 const [value, setValue] = React.useState(NavBarItem[location.pathname])

 const handleChange = (newValue, event) => {
  setValue(newValue)
 }

 const navigateTo = pathname => {
  history.push(pathname)
  handleChange(NavBarItem[pathname])
 }

 return (
  <div className={classes.root}>
   <AppBar position='static' color='primary'>
    <Tabs
     value={value}
     onChange={handleChange}
     className={classes.tabs}
     variant='scrollable'
     scrollButtons='on'
     indicatorColor='secondary'
     textColor='inherit'
     aria-label='scrollable force tabs example'
    >
     <Tab
      label='...'
      icon={<Event />}
      {...a11yProps(0)}
      onClick={() => navigateTo('/schedule')}
     />
     <Tab
      label='...'
      icon={<Equalizer />}
      {...a11yProps(1)}
      onClick={() => navigateTo('/reports')}
     />
     <Tab
      label='...'
      icon={<Apps />}
      {...a11yProps(2)}
      onClick={() => navigateTo('/utils')}
     />
     <Tab
      label='...'
      icon={<ShoppingBasket />}
      {...a11yProps(3)}
      onClick={() => navigateTo('/sale-management')}
     />
    </Tabs>
   </AppBar>
  </div>
 )
}

export default withRouter(NavBar)
```

Comment: Hello Michael,  I managed to solve this problem. However your solution also seems clean and I am going to try it. Thank you.